# Sum of date time difference in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql table columns are

```
Starttime - type:datetime, Stoptime - type:datetime
```

Data

```
Starttime, stoptime
2013-10-25 09:00:00, 2013-10-25 17:00:00
2013-10-26 09:00:00, 2013-10-26 17:00:00
2013-10-27 09:00:00, 2013-10-27 17:00:00
2013-10-28 09:00:00, 2013-10-28 17:45:00
```

Query

```
select, min(starttime), max(stoptime), 
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_DIFF(stoptime - starttime))) total_hours from mytable
```

returns a number of seconds which I can convert back to time using `TIME_TO_SEC()` ... it gives me result in the format `HH:MM:SS` e.g. 28:45:00

But I need to convert 28:45:00 into 28.75 hours format. How do I do that?

Comment: Try this:
`select, min(starttime), max(stoptime), 
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_DIFF(stoptime - starttime))/3600) total_hours from mytable`

Comment: Great.. that does the trick. if you post that as answer i'll accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select, min(starttime), max(stoptime), 
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_DIFF(stoptime - starttime))/3600) total_hours from mytable
```

Comment: Thanks - I don't need to use TIME_TO_SEC() now.

Comment: TIMEDIFF instead of TIME_DIFF and stoptime,starttime instead of stoptime-starttime

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
MIN(starttime), 
MAX(stoptime), 
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stoptime, starttime))/3600) AS total_hours 
FROM mytable
```