# How to extract in time using a single date column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi below table having time in and time out values .
for example my in time is `2015-05-14 09:21:19` and out time is `2015-05-14 11:20:51` and again in time is `2015-05-14 11:26:39` and out time is `2015-05-14 13:46:47` etc.

Now I want total in time in hours and minutes. How can I get it?.

```
+--------+----------+----------------
|     id| login    | intime         |
+--------+----------+----------------
|   345 | xyz | 2015-05-14 09:21:19 |
|   345 | xyz | 2015-05-14 11:20:51 |
|   345 | xyz | 2015-05-14 11:26:39 |
|   345 | xyz | 2015-05-14 13:46:47 |
|   345 | xyz | 2015-05-14 14:07:09 |
+--------+----------+----------------
```

Comment: This data set in incomplete, provide complete example and expected result.

Comment: What query you tried so far?

Comment: throwing error below query select t1.login ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,t1.intime,t2.intime) FROM UnnamedTableFromQuestion t1  INNER JOIN UnnamedTableFromQuestion t2   FROM employee_timings where emp_id='345' and row_create like '2015-05-14%';

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

This will return hh:mm:ss from fields.

```
select time(Intime)
```

This will return only hours

```
select hour(Intime)
```

This will return formated time -H:i

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Intime,"%H:%i")
```

Try This:

```
SELECT @i:=sum(unix_timestamp(intime)) FROM `test` where in_out=0;
SELECT @o:=sum(unix_timestamp(intime)) FROM `test` where in_out=1;
select @o:=if(@i>@o,@o+UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),@o); 
select @i, @o, TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME((@o-@i)),'%Hh %im');
```

Or use php to get sum in unix for IN time, Sum from unix for Out Time. And Get seconds between results

Comment: i want to subtract the time between every two rows using intime with a single query.finally to get the how many hours a person stayed inside. let us assume first two rows diff is 2hrs and next two rows diff is 3hrs and next two rows diff is 4hr..now i want total time(2+3+4=9).

Comment: Add new fields in your table and mark in and out time for each session and which time is IN and which time is OUT. And you can get time between In and Out grouped by session.

Comment: Remove comment // If is still logged if you try my example

Answer (score 0):

Try this : i cant get your question clearly, try like this
make try it`select SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, '0:00:00', intime)) as minuteas, SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, '0:00:00', intime)) as hours from table`

Comment: throwing error Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF' because mysql not supporting datediff.

Comment: sorry i used MS SQL  this this , there is good answer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051544/sum-of-date-time-difference-in-a-mysql-query